# You cannot create a branch at '' because a branch already exists at ''. If '' is not a branch convert it back to a folder and retry the operation

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

We keep getting this error whenever i try to create a new branch.

You cannot create a branch at $/Power Web Portal/UTMBSolutionsMaster/ProVostWebApps because a branch already exists at $/Power Web Portal/UTMBSolutionsMaster/ProVostWebApps/EmployeePortal-Teaching. If $/Power Web Portal/UTMBSolutionsMaster/ProVostWebApps/EmployeePortal-Teaching is not a branch convert it back to a folder and retry the operation.

I tried the tf delete command but its not able to find that branch as it has already been deleted. Here is a screenshot of the deleted branches

[image]

Can anyone please suggest how i can get rid of this error ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i tried to 'Undelete' the branch first and then i converted it to a folder(Rightclick > Branch > ConvertToFolder) and then deleted it again.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

To show deleted folder you need to go to 'Tool > Options > Source Control > Visual Studio TFS' and tick 'Show deleted items'. Then follow Surya's advice.